# QGIS Qfield visiblity of offline layers on Android 6.0 Samsung tablet Galaxy tab S2

Tags: qgis, android, qfield

I am running a brand new out of the box Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 with Android 6 and trying to get QGIS QField to operate correctly. So far I have created a QGIS project in QGIS desktop, packaged it with QfieldSync and uploaded it to the tablet, but I'm struggling to do anything with it.

It opens and I can see the individual layers in 'Digitise' but only the layer that I copied is visible in the data frame, the layers that I wish to edit and that are in 'offline editing' configuration are completely invisible. Is this normal (I am used to ArcGIS collector - where you can edit data and see it at the same time) ? I'd like to be able to see the existing data in these layers while I edit it. Is this possible and have a made an error or is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is probably due to some 'corrupt' geometry issues (polygon and multipolygon features in line or polygon layers). See the answer in the following thread: [Gpkg and shapefiles behave differently (gpkg is not visible) in QField offline editing mode](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354006/gpkg-and-shapefiles-behave-differently-gpkg-is-not-visible-in-qfield-offline-e)

Thank you Matthias ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Having tested vector layers packaged in QFieldSync as both 'copy' and 'offline editing' I have now determined that for pre-existing features to be visible in QField a layer needs to be set to 'copy'. If layers are set to 'offline editing' the existing features cannot be seen, presumably to aid syncrhonisation. If you need to undertake offline editing and see a the existing features in a layer it is advisable to put two versions in the QFieldSync package, one set to 'copy' and one to 'offline editing'.

Comment: Setting up a 'copy' and 'offline editing' layer is a nice workaround though ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same experience with some line and polygon GPKG layers. Not with points though, although these were from a different project.

What did help was exporting the GPKG to Shapefiles. Then Offline editing goes without any problem. It seems the solution for this particular project, although I rather work with GPKG instead of SHP.

I run qgis 3.4.15 and an old (2014) samsung tab4 with the latest and updated qfield.

I wonder if more users have this problem.