# Geopackage is not visible in QField offline editing mode

Tags: qgis-3, qfield, qfieldsync

I am using QGIS 3.4.9 Madeira and QField 1.4.4.
Having a gpkg and shp layer with the same information in a project and transferring them both to QField (both layers are set to offline editing), only the shapefile layer is visible. The gpkg file is not visible.

- Although gpkg file is not visible, it is editable! When I add a polygon, I see the new polygon in QField with the symbology as set in the QGIS project.
- I have the same issue with a line layer, but not with a point layer
- When using QFieldSync, the plugin asks me always: `"do you want to save the changes in the layer Survey_V_Vlakken (offline)"?` In other words, it seems that QFieldSync makes a new layer for mobile/offline use?
- Synchronizing back with QField, the changes in the gpkg and shp layers are added to the QGIS project
- First I was using a *.QGZ project (as the default in QGIS 3.4) but I also tried *.QGS and is does not make any difference.
- Both layers have the same CRS 31370 (Belgian Lambert)

Does anyone knows how I can make the gpkg file visible? In a similar question somebody added the same gpkg file as a copy for the QField project; in that way it was visible. But this is not a very handy solution...

[Link so similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246947/qgis-qfield-visiblity-of-offline-layers-on-android-6-0-samsung-tablet-galaxy-tab)

[image: Printscreen question QFieldSync]

[image: Printscreen QField shp layer]

[image: Printscreen QField project layers]

Answer (score 2):

Problem resolved!
With a very big thank you @Matthias from OpenGis.ch who was spot on identifying the problem.

[image]

I run the Vector > Geometry > Multiple to single algorithm for both layers (polygon and line layer) that didn’t show up.
1/ I found one polygon that was a multi-polygon > when it was fixed, the layer showed up in QField!
2/ Somehow the same problem in the line layer > also fixed!
And no longer a question about saving that offline file after running QFieldSync.